# Setting transparency for range of colors in raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, color, transparency-opacity

**The starting point:** Loading a raster to QGIS, you can set individual colors to transparent in the Panel `Layer styling / Tab Transparency` by activating the icon `Add values from display` and click on the map canvas. The color of the selected raster pixel will be set to transparent (see screenshot below).

**The problem and what I tried:** As can be seen in the screenshot, often (especially using georeferenced jpg-images) what for the eye is one color, technically consists of several different colors with very similar values for red/green/blue: different shades of the same color. Of course, you could repeatedly use the `Add values from display` and click on the map to add further colors to the transparency setting.

**The question:** However, this can be annoying. Is there a way to select a range of colors to be set to transparent? I'm looking for something like tools known from image processing software like Photoshop or Affinity Photo, e.g. the `Flood Select Tool` in Affinity Photo: [Tolerance—sets the range of pixels affected when a pixel is clicked](https://affinity.help/photo/English.lproj/index.html?page=pages/Tools/tools_floodSelect.html?title=Flood%20Select%20Tool).

***Screenshot**: Only part of the see is set to transparent (RGB value: 221/242/247), showing the OpenStreetMap basemap in the background. Neighboring pixels with - let's say - RGB 225/240/243 are still opaque:*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

Even if you could set a tolerance, you wouldn't get all of the sea, and you would still have text in the sea ('Mittelsee' etc).

**Possible Solution**

You might be better served by using a vector coastline map to select and copy only the areas of the georeferenced raster that you want to keep. Put it in a separate raster. Remove the original raster. This will also tell you if your georeferencing was good.

Use **gdalwarp** to perform the clipping. It will create a new raster. Load it in QGIS. Copy the style of your original raster and paste it to the new raster if necessary.

You may need to **put a small buffer on the coastline** so you don't have sharp edges.

Finally, put your own **water layer *underneath*** using bathymetry data, etc.